# How to add class to HTML element on marker click with Leaflet JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet

So, I'm trying to show a modal when a marker is clicked as a part of my Leaflet app. I already have some of the click functionality set on my marker layer, but I seem to be failing in triggering the necessary class being added to the modal element.

Currently I have a modal div with the following HTML outside of my map div.:

```
<div class="modal" id="infoBox">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<header class="modal-header"><button class="close-modal" aria-label="close modal" data-close> X</button></header>
<p>
<section class="modal-content">
Address: <span id="street"></span><br/>
Neighborhood: <span id="suburb"></span><br/>   
City: <span id="city"></span><br/>
Piece Type: <span id="type"></span><br/>
Description: <span id="desc"></span><br/>
</p>
</section>
<footer class="modal-footer"></footer>
</div>    
</div>
```

I am trying to add the class with the following function:

```
function zoomToFeature(e) {
  var latLngs = [e.target.getLatLng()];
  var markerBounds = L.latLngBounds(latLngs);
  var street = e.target.feature.properties.str_addr;
  var city = e.target.feature.properties.city;
  var desc = e.target.feature.properties.desc;
  document.getElementById('street').textContent = street;
  document.getElementById('city').textContent = city;
  document.getElementById('desc').textContent = desc;
  mymap.fitBounds(markerBounds);
  mymap.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
  document.getElementById('infoBox').classList.add('is-visible');
}
```

Which I add the click listener on the layer with the onEachFeature function like so:

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer){
    layer.on({
        mouseover: highlightFeature,
        mouseout: resetHighlight,
        click: zoomToFeature,
    });
}
```

When I manually add the `.is-visible` class the element I get the expected behaviour, but clicking the marker layer doesn't add the class. I'm basically trying to implement this [Tutsplus Tutorial](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-build-flexible-modal-dialogs-with-html-css-and-javascript--cms-33500) with some of the functionality in the Leaflet [Chrolopleth tutorial](https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/). The click functionality works as far as pulling the feature info and zooming to the marker, but as above the modal stays hidden.

Running the classListAdd in a stand alone function in the dev console adds the class like so `class="modal is-visible"` but it doesn't trigger the functionality. As above manually changing the class to `modal.is-visible` does work, but I assume that's because it's an exact match for the css and it's not being re-interpreted.

Stripped down demo version can be [seen here](http://138.197.1.44/testsite/)

Comment: Could you provide a live reproduction example, e.g. using http://leafletjs.com/edit ?

Comment: So, this stripped down version https://plnkr.co/edit/J1zeTgYiNC2ZC86Y?preview works for me locally, but I don't get enough from the console to get it to work...

Comment: added live version on my droplet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is the line: `e.target.getBounds()`

When you click on a (Circle)Marker, `e.target` is that Marker. But Point features do not have such `getBounds()` method (since they represent a single point, not an area).

So your script fails with an error like:

> Uncaught TypeError: e.target.getBounds is not a function

...and the rest of the event listener is not executed, in particular the following line where you show your modal (`document.getElementById('infoBox').classList.add('is-visible')`)

Since you already set the view around that Marker just before (`mymap.fitBounds(markerBounds)`), there is no need to that repeated call (maybe just a leftover of previous attempts?)

Removing that line restores your modal behaviour.

Fixed Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/DfCKrJaNzM48dzuZ

Note: your Plunkr was not working because you forgot the call to your `initMap()` function.